# Kann ich Sie kurz sprechen? (Sie oder Ihnen?)

Tags: dative, accusative

Why is it Sie instead of Ihnen here?

Kann ich Sie kurz sprechen?

Shouldn't it be like this:

Kann ich Ihnen kurz sprechen?

Can I speak TO YOU or WITH YOU for a moment?
Both should be in dative case.

Answer (score 4):

The German verb phrase in question does neither use *zu* nor *mit* as you can easily see. It's *jemande**n** sprechen*, hence accusative case. There's also the verb phrases *mit jemandem sprechen* and *zu jemandem sprechen* but neither of both is relevant here.

It's true that German dative objects can often be replaced by *to X* in English. But that's not always the case as English knows indirect objects. And neither can an English *to X* always be replaced by a dative object in German. Those are only rules of thumb.

Comment: It is not necessary to have zu, mit or any other similar prepositions to form a dative case. For example: Ich habe es ihm gekauft. Ihm is dative here only because it implies for him.

Comment: Yes. It's a plain dative object. The verb *kaufen* has a mandatory accusative object and an optional dative object. — But the verb *sprechen* does not have a dative object. At all. You have to memorize the types of objects for each German verb. The easiest way is to memorize *jemande**n** sprechen*. Better dictionaries put the verb phrases exactly like that: *jmd**n** sprechen*.

Comment: The main problem seems to be that English "to" can function as a marker for a second object ("dative object") or it can function as a directional preposition. The question seems to assume that this is the same, but the two must be kept apart. In "speak to somebody" it is not the "dative-to" even in English. Cf. German: "zu einem Publikum sprechen". It's purely directional. On the other hand, "deny something to somebody" is not directional (because nothing is to be received here).

Answer (score 2):

It's true that this is a somewhat special construction. "Jemanden sprechen" (instead of "mit jemandem") means to talk to someone in a formal context, when this person has a particular office or duty or capacity, and you are pursuing a goal which relates to that.

https://www.dwds.de/wb/sprechen#d-1-2